# Is there a more efficient way to say a decimal place in decimal number?

Tags: numbers

Let's say there is a number 12.3456789.

From what I have learned, 1 is tens, 2 is ones, 3 is tenths, 4 is hundredths, 5 is thousandths, 6 is probably ten-thousandth?

Is there any way more efficient than that to indicate decimal places in English? It feels very mouthful when the number has many decimal places like if there's a number 0.123456789 and I want to say 7 is at [place] for example.

Comment: You can also use cardinal numbers: "the seventh decimal" is the same as "one ten millionth".

Comment: In the quantity 1.4873, there is a seven in the _third place_ of decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0.123456**7**89

As you mentioned, the first decimal position (to the right of the point) is the number of tenths, the second the hundreds, the third the thousandths, the fourth the ten-thousandths, the fifth the hundred-thousandths, the sixth the millionths, etc.

We could say:

> There is a 7 **in the seventh decimal position**.

> There is a 7 **in the seventh decimal place**.

For example:

> 34.678 = 34.68 (rounded up because 8 is **in the third decimal place**) ([St Roberts Physics](https://strobertsphysics.wordpress.com/significant-figures/))

Some people would say:

> **The seventh decimal** is a 7.

For example:

> if the number in the third decimal place is less than 5, **the second decimal** remains unchanged (for example, €1.264 becomes €1.26) ([European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/info/business-economy-euro/euro-area/introducing-euro/adoption-fixed-euro-conversion-rate/converting-euro_en))

Answer (score 0):

It is such an uncommon situation outside of maths class.  We don't often need to refer to individual digits out of context of the whole number. It is hard for me to imagine a situation in which you would actually need to do this.

Given a number like 29034.4058032  You could say "There is a 3 in the millionths column"  or "the sixth number after the decimal point is 3".

If you were just reading the number you don't need this: "twenty-nine thousand (and), thirty four point four zero five eight zero three two"  It would almost always be easier to refer to the whole number, rather than to just one digit.

> I've found the error in the code, and it's only a little one.  On line 383 the constant should be 29034.40580***5***2 and not 29034.40580***3***2. Isn't it amazing that such a small mistake could cause the rocket to explode!?